# How do I check how many times a mocked method was called?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jmock

I have a mock that has been set up in an `@Before` method:

```
  @Before
  public void setup() {
    mockery.checking(new Expectations() {
      {
        allowing(mockExecutor).schedule(with(capture(runnableRef, Runnable.class)), with(0L), with(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
      }
    });
  }
```

I've tried adding a specific expectation to this test case (just checking against 1 here):

```
mockery.checking(new Expectations() {
  {
    exactly(1).of(mockExecutor).schedule(with(capture(runnableRef, Runnable.class)), with(0L), with(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
  }
});
```

However in the results I can see that it's never hitting this new expectation as it hits the "allowed" first:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: not all expectations were satisfied
expectations:
  allowed, already invoked 1 time: scheduledExecutorService.schedule(captured value <com.rbsfm.common.db.async.impl.ThrottledExecutor$1@eafc191>, <0L>, 
  expected once, never invoked: scheduledExecutorService.schedule(captured value <com.rbsfm.common.db.async.impl.ThrottledExecutor$1@eafc191>, <0L>,
```

In most of the unit tests I do not care how often the `schedule` method has been called (and it does vary from test to test), however in one test I wish to check that it has been called exactly 2 times.

Is there any way to do this without having to repeat the mock configuration for each test with different numbers?

For example can I query the `Mockery` to find out how often the method has been called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This scenario is discussed here: http://www.jmock.org/override.html (Thanks to Dick Hermann who pointed me to the page).

The basic idea is that you set up a state machine for the test and only have the expectation active when the state machine is in the correct state using `when`.

```
public class ChildTest extends TestCase {
    Mockery context = new Mockery();
    States test = context.states("test");

    Parent parent = context.mock(Parent.class);

    // This is created in setUp
    Child child;

    @Override
    public void setUp() {
        context.checking(new Expectations() {{
            ignoring (parent).addChild(child); when(test.isNot("fully-set-up"));
        }});

        // Creating the child adds it to the parent
        child = new Child(parent);

        test.become("fully-set-up");
    }

    public void testRemovesItselfFromOldParentWhenAssignedNewParent() {
        Parent newParent = context.mock(Parent.class, "newParent");

        context.checking(new Expectations() {{
            oneOf (parent).removeChild(child);
            oneOf (newParent).addChild(child);
        }});

        child.reparent(newParent);
    }
}
```